# After how many months can one revisit USA on a multiple entry B-1/B-2 visa?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, repeat-visits

I visited New York City on a B-1/B-2 visa last month.

Is there any time limit restriction for going to another US city?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How soon can I re-enter the USA having stayed for 90 days under the Visa Waiver Program?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13964/how-soon-can-i-re-enter-the-usa-having-stayed-for-90-days-under-the-visa-waiver)

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not. Basically you need to be able to show that your trip complies with the requirements, among others that you not use the B visa to live in the US, and that you will not exceed your allowed period of stay (generally six months for each admission).

Answer (score 0):

I think this question now arises more than in the past because the I-94 is electronic and people do not see it. When it was paper, it said "admit until..." and had a date usually six months into the future. Now you can check your I-94 at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/ . What that means is you are good to stay until that day in the USA. Whether you do that stay in one go or interrupt it as many times as you want doesn't matter. (You need a multiple entry visa.) I have left the USA on a Monday and went back on a Thursday the same week and noone bat an eye.

Basically, the B1/B2 almost guarantees an entry at the border because the very point of the visa is to give you a deeper check than the border guard could.

Of course, nothing is a surefire guarantee, the last word is always at the discretion of the border official but you need to do something truly extreme to be not allowed in.

Comment: What you say is true for residents of Canada, and possibly of Mexico and the Caribbean, but if one is traveling from (for example) Europe, one gets a new I-94 each time with a fresh six-month period of admission. The "admit until" date is written in the passport; no need to look it up online.

Comment: I checked my passport before writing this and the stamps only say "admitted on". Meanwhile, the [electronic I-94](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/502386%20-%20I-94%20Fact%20Sheet_OFO.pdf) has an "admitted until" field. And getting a new I-94 does not invalidate what I said: you are already cleared to stay until the old date so re-admitting shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: the stamp has a line under the "admitted" date that is labeled "class until"; this is where the officer writes the date by which the traveler must leave (as well as the class of admission, for example, B-2). When there's a paper I-94, they don't generally write it in the passport, but for an electronic I-94, they do. When you get a new I-94, you typically get a new six months unless you're resident in, or returning from a short trip to, an adjacent country.

Comment: When you reside in and fly from Canada you generally get a new (electronic) I-94 and 6 month stay on every entry, it is people with paper I-94's at the land border that have the option of reusing the paper. I can confirm, though, that when I was a frequent APC kiosk user they would almost always omit the "admit until" date from the stamp, often leave off the "B-?" part too, and maybe one time in six not bother with a stamp at all (the stamps went away entirely when I moved to the GE kiosks). I think the stamp slackness might be a Canada thing and not generally representative, though.

Comment: "What that means is you are good to stay until that day in the USA. Whether you do that stay in one go or interrupt it as many times as you want doesn't matter." NO. This is only how long you can stay on *that stay*. Each entry for visitor status is independent and when you were admitted until in the past has no relation what you will be admitted until, or whether you will even be admitted, in any future entry (the exception is if you are seeking to be re-admitted on automatic revalidation after a short trip to Mexico or Canada).

Comment: @user102008 another exception is VWP travelers, who can be admitted for the remainder of their prior 90-day period of admission.