# Is there a certain period of time we should wait before visiting Japan again (Visit limits)?

Tags: japan, repeat-visits

I am looking to visit Japan soon, but I am conflicted about how long I want to stay in the country (within the 90 day Tourist visit), and when I will be going.  I would love to stay the full 90 days, but I would like to go for a shorter period of time, the first time I go.

I have read that people have gotten flagged for going to Japan, then another country, and back to Japan again within a few month period.  I have heard you are only given entry a few times (I heard 3), as a tourist (even though I read recently someone just got back from their 12th trip).  So I am not sure what is true, and if you can only go so many times.

So my questions are, are there limitations to how long you have to wait before going back to Japan, and are there limits to the amount of times one can visit the country?

I figured if I can only go a few times total, and cannot do it within x amount of time I would maximize my stay, but if I could go twice within the next 8 or so months then I would rather do that.

Note I was thinking November for a few weeks, and then February or so the second time, so I'm not sure if that is enough time between the 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer - there's not always a specific time. It depends on your situation.

Any time you re-visit a country within a short time can and should raise questions.  For example: [visiting the US soon after being there for 90 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13964/101).

However, the point of these questions is to establish your right or reason to be there. If it's valid and they don't think you're trying to 'live' unofficially in the country, for example, they'll let you through.

It's not about how long since your last visit (although that can be part of it), but about your intentions, as perceived by the officer questioning you.

On a personal vote, I visited Japan, then flew to the US and Canada, and was back in Japan 3 weeks later. No questions, no problem.  I'm also going again this September.

My friend is getting married to a Japanese girl, and he's probably visited five times in the last 18 months - again, no problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for  the information presented in this answer.  I should have no problem visiting both times (and hopefully more in the future) then.  I have a bunch of other questions related to my trip, but I am not sure if I can ask here, or if I should create other questions (is there a limit to how many questions I can ask in a row)?

Comment: @XaolingBao no limit, but definitely ask separate questions - one per post. Have a look at the [help] if uncertain, or join the [chat] :)

Comment: Some countries have legal limits on how often you can visit, though Japan does not.

Comment: So, where is answer for the question?

Comment: @Rambalac well the OP upvoted and accepted the answer, so it certainly seems like it was ok. However I see what you mean so I'll edit a bit.

Comment: I've left a country and came back into the same day without issue - returning from a business trip in the country that neighbours mine, then going to a different city on a vacation in that country with a family member. No issue. Note, these were trips of less than a week. The total time (eg are you trying to get 180 days out of 185 by making 2 90-day trips with a 5 day gap?) matters more than the time between visits.

Answer (score 4):

By Japanese rules as tourist you can stay in the country up to 180 days per a year and 90 days per visit. There is no any required period to stay outside of Japan after one visit. But immigration officer has right to refuse you to enter if he thinks you are going to stay longer than 180 days (for example staid 60 day, than 90 days and want enter again).

If you come for short time like 1 month then there should be no any problem to come in few days for another 90 days.

http://www.my.emb-japan.go.jp/English/visit.html

Comment: Thank you, this is good information... I will keep that in mind that the duration matters more than how many times back and forth.  It seemed to me that I read something where someone got all sorts of questions when going back and forth, but other people on here seem to disagree with that notion.

Answer (score 2):

Because you made a generic question, I answer generically.

Often tourist visa are for X days within a Y days period. Often it is: 90 days over 180 or 360 days. This mean that you can stay maximum 90 days every half or entire year.

If you needs more days in a year, probably (in country point of view) you are not a tourist, so you need to apply for educational, visiting people, volunteering, business, etc.

You may be required (and usually it is) a different visa for every 90-day stays.

Comment: This is not the case for Japan though, since they don't publish any official limits.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Second this comment

Answer (score 1):

Last year (2016), I went to Japan for 3 months as a consultant, but with a tourist visa. I told immigration that I was there to work as a consultant sent by my company; they asked only for my business card. I took a week off to go to Korea, then back to Japan for two weeks, before finally returning to the US, where I live.

On my return to Japan from Korea, they didn't asked anything.

This year (2017), I went again to work for over a month to Japan; after my work was done, I went to Korea for a week, then went back to Japan and left to return to the US.

On my return to Japan, they asked about my residency; I told them I would  leave for the US in a couple of days and showed my flight's ticket. They allowed me to enter Japan without any other problem.

From my experience, I can say that it all depends on your ability to show that you are not planning on living in Japan, and if you say a few words in Japanese it helps.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how you managed to do what you said in 2016, since I've read that as a Tourist (Visa-Free) you aren't allowed to work, so are you sure you didn't get a work visa of some sort?  You also said you got a tourist visa, but I also read that there aren't any visas needed for being a tourist (really not sure what a visa fully is, If it's an extra form of documentation, or just a stamp in your passport).

Thanks for the information overall.

Comment: When I say visa I mean the stamp they give you when landing. And when I went there for work I was a US employee leading a team in Japan (and other countries) from the US, I only went for  couple of months because it was easier to manage the team in the same timezone, I hope this clarify the confusion.