# Can I enter the US twice within 90 days?

Tags: usa, airport-transfer, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

Can I visit the US twice within a 90 day period under the Visa Waiver Programme? 2nd time is only to transfer (change terminal, not airside).

Comment: Because the title is just a title, and not intended for the entire question - you really overfilled it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the minimum wait before I may I re-enter the USA after a 90 day visit on the Visa Waiver Program?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10446/what-is-the-minimum-wait-before-i-may-i-re-enter-the-usa-after-a-90-day-visit-on)

Comment: @user77409 Different question. That question is specifically about making long visits, which isn't mentioned at all in this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VWP doesn't have a "so many days in so many other days" thing like the EU 90/180 rule.  Every entry, you get to make your case to the Immigration Officer as to why you should be admitted.  You can come *every weekend* if you have a reasonable reason that makes sense to the officers and doesn't seem to conflict with US immigration law or policy.

In your case, you'll want to have your onward transportation departing the United States, and it wouldn't hurt to have some proof of a bona-fide activity in that destination country.

And as always, it helps to have proof of "ties to home country" and "adequate funding for trip" and all the usual things they want to see to know that you're not likely to remain illegally.

Also in your favor is that you were admitted under VWP before, and that your previous stay was uneventful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you kindly have a reputable source that says I can enter as many times as I want? Those immigration officers are not friendly in my experience...

Comment: @Noobius There's no "reputable source" for your assertion because your assertion isn't true: there is no legal "right" or "entitlement" to multiple VWP entries. Still, you may be able to enter multiple times if, as Harper explained, you can convince the CBP officer that you have a good reason to enter and you'll leave again when you're supposed to.