# Taiwanese to U.S. travel

Tags: usa, taiwanese-citizens

After a Taiwanese citizen has visited the U.S. and returned to Taiwan,  how long must they stay in Taiwan before returning to the U.S. again?

Comment: Assuming they are traveling under the Visa Waiver Program, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10446/what-is-the-minimum-wait-before-i-may-i-re-enter-the-usa-after-a-90-day-visit-on.

Comment: Only as long as it takes to check in and board another flight.