# how many days per calendar year can I visit the US

Tags: esta

I have a us ESTA and have been to the US this year for two separate 90 visits since April, totally 187 days on US soil. I know there is no limit to the number of times you can enter the country, but is there a limit to how many days you can be in US per calendar year?

Comment: Have you read [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10446/what-is-the-minimum-wait-before-i-may-re-enter-the-usa-after-a-90-day-visit-on-t)?  Could you let us know what factual matters in your question remain unanswered by it?  Personally, I'm slightly surprised they let you in for the second visit, and would expect definite problems with a third, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: How were you in the US for 187 days on two 90-day visits? And, congratulations, you may have a tax headache now as well.